# How to detect when scrollbar has focus?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar

Simple question: Is it possible in jQuery to detect a mousedown event on the scrollbar or scrollbar track, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if mousedown can be tracked on the scrollbar but if you're using jquery you can use the scroll function to bind an event to the scrollbar position changes.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    console.log("foo")
});
```

[jQuery Scroll documentation](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar is part of the browser and there is no way to tell if the mouse button was pressed on it. Besides using your own scrollbar in the page, the closest you can go is to detect if the user scrolled, using the [`scroll()` event.](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)

Also, not all browsers/operating systems can have 'focus' on the scrollbar.

Comment: This is simply not true. You can do this, there's just no cross-browser solution because some browsers (webkit *cough*) don't give up the information.

Comment: FF, at least on Linux, does not even -blur- your focused element